# Cannot delete all characters from a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

In my application, there is a possibility to add transactions. The transaction has an attribute called amount and this attribute is a Double. I have implemented the function to add a negative and a positive amount. I do this with a `UISegmentedControll`. If the user makes the amount negative, the `amountTextField.text`gets to  `"-" + amountTextField.text. That the user can input just Doubles I added this function :

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let oldText = textField.text, let r = Range(range, in: oldText) else{
            return true
        }
        let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: r, with: string)
        let isNumeric = newText.isEmpty || (Double(newText) != nil)
        let numberOfDots = newText.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1

        let numberOfDecimalDigits: Int
        if let dotIndex = newText.index(of: "."){
            numberOfDecimalDigits = newText.distance(from: dotIndex, to: newText.endIndex) - 1
        } else {
            numberOfDecimalDigits = 0
        }
        return isNumeric && numberOfDots <= 1 && numberOfDecimalDigits <= 2
    }
```

When there is a minus in front of the positive Double, it is impossible to delete the first number of the string. For example if the amountTextField.text is -399.99, and the user presses the delete button as often as he wants, the textField will show -3. In my debugging work I found out that the function I added to the code is the reason for this.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you care if the user types "1.23" then moves the insertion point to the left of the "dot" and deletes the "1", leaving "-.23" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let oldText = textField.text, let r = Range(range, in: oldText) else {
        return true
    }

    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: r, with: string)

    if newText == "-" {
        // result will be "-" so just
        return true
    }

    let isNumeric = newText.isEmpty || (Double(newText) != nil)
    let numberOfDots = newText.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1

    let numberOfDecimalDigits: Int
    if let dotIndex = newText.index(of: "."){
        numberOfDecimalDigits = newText.distance(from: dotIndex, to: newText.endIndex) - 1
    } else {
        numberOfDecimalDigits = 0
    }


    if isNumeric && numberOfDots <= 1 && numberOfDecimalDigits <= 2 {
        // value passes those tests, so make sure the leading "-" is still there
        // if not, prepend it, set the text and return false
        if newText.first != "-" {
            textField.text = "-" + newText
            return false
        }
    }

    return isNumeric && numberOfDots <= 1 && numberOfDecimalDigits <= 2
}
```

We have a couple of additional `if` blocks to handle:

- user moves the insertion point to delete the "-"
- user does a "select all" and taps a new digit or delete, or pastes a value

I expect you already know you'll also want a bool check to handle this differently if the segmented control is **not** in the negative position.

Comment: That works as I expected it. Thank you for that. I'm fine with this solution :D

Comment: Oh no I found a bug. If the user switches back to the positive way and then enters a character, the textfield shows a minus again.

Comment: Yes... see the last line in my answer: *"I expect you already know you'll also want..."*